# JSON Decode not receiving data

Tags: javascript, php, json, stripe-payments

I am trying to use the Stripe API to create a payment form as detailed here:
https://stripe.com/docs/payments/integration-builder

I would like to send the amout (that the user is charged) from the front-end so have attempted to add it to the fetch request as shown below:

```
var purchase = {
  //items: [{ id: "xl-tshirt", price: 400 }]
  amount: 2000
};

// Disable the button until we have Stripe set up on the page
document.querySelector("button").disabled = true;
fetch("/create.php", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(purchase)
});
```

However the value (currently hardcoded at 2000) is not pulling through to the POST body successfully and the payment intent is failing. Below is the code I am using:

```
try {
  // retrieve JSON from POST body
  $json_str = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $json_obj = json_decode($json_str, false);
  $paymentIntent = \Stripe\PaymentIntent::create([
    //'amount' => calculateOrderAmount($json_obj->items),
    'amount' => $json_obj['amount'],
    'currency' => 'usd',
  ]);
  $output = [
    'clientSecret' => $paymentIntent->client_secret,
  ];
  echo json_encode($output);
} catch (Error $e) {
  http_response_code(500);
  echo json_encode(['error' => $e->getMessage()]);
}
```

Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: So what did your received data in `$json_str` actually contain?

Comment: @CBroe Nothing is returned if I try and use var_dump or echo - the only error I am getting I can see in the network is "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array"

Comment: I have changed ` $json_obj = json_decode($json_str, false);`  to   `$json_obj = json_decode($json_str, true);` and now get 
{"clientSecret":"xxx-yyy-zzz"}string(15) "{"amount":2000}"
{"amount":2000}

Answer (score 1):

You are sending `false` here, that converts it into an `object`

```
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str, false);
```

Then you are trying to use it as an `array` here

```
'amount' => $json_obj['amount'],
```

Try using

```
'amount' => $json_obj->amount,
```

Or

```
$json_obj = json_decode($json_str, true);
```

without changing anything else.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated to use `$json_obj = json_decode($json_str, true);` and still getting 500 in the console.

Comment: have you defined the stripe client using your test secret key?